# Get text of parent dt in Description List

Tags: jquery-mobile, parent

I have a JQuery Mobile popup (an unordered list) embedded in a description list:

```
<dl data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" id="sortable">
<dt class="ui-bar ui-bar-b ui-corner-all">Group One</dt>
<dd class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-bars">
    <div class="divMain">
        <div class="divQuestion">
            <textarea name="strQuestion-q1" id="strQuestion-q1" placeholder="Enter Question Number 1" style="margin:0px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="divCategory">
            <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" href="#popupMenu-q1" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup">Select Category</a>
            <div id="popupMenu-q1" data-role="popup" data-theme="b">
                <ul style="min-width: 210px;" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Choose the scoring category</li>
                    <li><a name="strCategory-o1-q1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selectCategory(this);">Category 1</a></li>
                    <li><a name="strCategory-o2-q1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selectCategory(this);">Category 2</a></li>
                    <li><a name="strCategory-o3-q1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selectCategory(this);">Category 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</dd>
</dl>
```

I want the function selectCategory() to get the text of the parent dt (in this case "Group One"). I've tried both of the following with no success:

```
$('#strCategory-o1-q1').parent().prev('dt').text();
$('#strCategory-o1-q1').closest('dd').prev('dt').text();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when jQM initializes the popup, it moves it from the current DOM position into a popup container at the top level. So the DD is no longer its ancestor.

One thing you could do is add a click handler to the button that launches the popup and get the text there. Then you could put the text in a global variable or a data-attribute within the popup.

Given this markup:

```
<a id="btnPopup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" href="#popupMenu-q1" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup">Select Category</a>

<div id="popupMenu-q1" data-role="popup" data-theme="b">
    <ul style="min-width: 210px;" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Choose the scoring category</li>
        <li><a name="strCategory-o1-q1"  href="#">Category 1</a></li>
        <li><a name="strCategory-o2-q1" href="#">Category 2</a></li>
        <li><a name="strCategory-o3-q1" href="#">Category 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your script would be along the lines of

```
var curDDText;

$("#btnPopup").on("click", function(){
    curDDText = $(this).closest('dd').prev('dt').text();
});

$("#popupMenu-q1 ul li a").on("click", function(e){
    selectCategory(this);
});

function selectCategory(elem){
    alert($(elem).prop("name") + "  -  " + curDDText);
    $("#popupMenu-q1").popup( "close" );
}
```

> working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/op248z7j/)**

If you prefer the data-attribute route:

```
$("#btnPopup").on("click", function(){
    var curDDText = $(this).closest('dd').prev('dt').text();
    $("#popupMenu-q1 ul").jqmData("dttext", curDDText);
});

function selectCategory(elem){
    var curDDText = $(elem).closest("ul").jqmData("dttext");
    alert($(elem).prop("name") + "  -  " + curDDText);
    $("#popupMenu-q1").popup( "close" );
}
```

> data-attribute **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/op248z7j/1/)**

Comment: What an awesome answer! I've adapted your first solution using classes instead of ids (because there are multiple <dd></dd> inside each <dl>. It's working perfectly for the first row but not for row 2+. See http://jsfiddle.net/5rfe7nmx/

Comment: @Dion, change prev('dt') to prevAll('dt'): http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5rfe7nmx/1/  prev() only looks at the immediate sibling while prevAll() looks at all previous siblings. As long as you only have on DT for many DD, it should work.

Comment: fantastic! I've got numerous DTs so I used prevAll('dt:first') and it's now working perfectly. I've spent days trying to figure this out and it was driving me crazy. Thank you. Plus, not only did you solve this problem but because your answer is so comprehensive, you taught me a much more elegant solution to a previous problem. If I could vote twice I would...